# Need specific scrip_code from csv on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a CSV of thousands of records, I am going to get a specific script and for that I need to find a specific scripcode based on multiple column parameters. For Example, Reliance price value is 2484 and now I want to search a Derevative Contract "D" in ExchType, Expiry should be nearest, Partof script code as "RELIANCE", CPType as "CE" and strike which is next to the price (2484).

[CSV file link:](http://content.indiainfoline.com/IIFLTT/Scripmaster.csv)

a sample code to filter the right scripcode would be great help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.